# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in cordapp-example-release-V3

Tags: java, corda

Whenever I run the Run Example Cordapp-Java, I am getting this error. I am new to Corda, learning from corda docs. Please, help me out.

```
at net.corda.testing.driver.DriverParameters.<init>(Driver.kt)   
at com.example.NodeDriver.main(NodeDriver.java:32)
[quasar] ERROR: java/lang/Object
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: Add more logcat error please

Comment: @Joel - java 9 using.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting exactly the same error. I was using jdk-10.0.1. When I switched to jdk1.8.0_171, it is working fine. I haven't figured out what in jdk-10.0.1 is causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

As of Corda 3.1, only Oracle JDK 8 JVM is supported, with a minimum version of 8u131.

You can see the required JDK version here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar error cause the default java version for my Ubuntu was changed to 11 which I haven't realized, though the project configuration has Java version as 1.8. Later, I changed the system's JDK default to 8 and everything started working normally.

Thanks to @Joel I read his comment